# Java 8 streams unexpected behaviour

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

This code returns the length of the longest String in a list of Strings. I have two solutions of which one works and the other doesn't

#### Correct

```
System.out.println(listOfConsecutiveOneStrings.stream()
    .max(Comparator.comparing(String::length))
    .max(Comparator.comparing(String::length))
    .map(onesSequence -> onesSequence.length())
    .get());
```

#### Wrong

```
System.out.println(listOfConsecutiveOneStrings.stream()
    .max(Comparator.comparing(String::length))
    .map(onesSequence -> onesSequence.length())
    .max(Integer::max)
    .get());
```

Why is the first snippet correct and the second one incorrect?

Comment: both of methods look not correctly

Comment: I think you should map the length, then get the max of the integers. I'm not sure why you seem to be sorting the list first

Comment: `max()` doesn't have the such signature